# Handling Tables by Column

Tags: jquery

I'm searching for a way to swap table columns around 
By some parameters (We are talking about jQuery or what not) 
And sort of a more general question: is there some kind of 
good JS library to handle tables by columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery Flexigrid plugin works great for sortable columns and lots of other things.
[Flexigrid Website](http://flexigrid.info/)

I use this all the time with single-page ASP.NET / WCF applications.  When I use ASP.NET MVC, I use [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/index) althought I am not 100% sure it allows for the column re-ordering like you want.

Comment: seems that the Bandwidth Limit has been Exceeded... too bad, no matter, I went to http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/ instead